# version_compare giving -1 when comparing 2019c & 2019a

Tags: php

```
echo version_compare("2019c", "2019a");
```

The output is `-1`, But it should be `1` since `2019c` is greater than `2019a`

I expect output of `echo version_compare("2019c", "2019a")` in PHP to `1`.

Comment: `version_compare` only works with numerical version strings.

Comment: No. for other alpha numeric it is working.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: false, `version_compare` also work with these string: `dev, alpha/a, beta/b, RC/rc, #, pl/p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php)

> version_compare — Compares two "PHP-standardized" version number
>   strings

`2019c` and `2019a` are not "PHP-standardized" version number

Comment: I am basically comparing version of Linux/Unix packages. So it will not always in the PHP standard. Which is the best option i can use here ?

Comment: The best option is to follow the standard versioning used by PHP, PHP version grows from `alpha/a` to `beta/b` to `RC/rc`. Another way is to create your own version compare function if you want to stick to a non-standard versioning method.

Comment: I am confused on which logic i need to use for custom fuction. Because for each linux package the version and release are different format. Could you please help on the idea to follow or if it is already done by someone please redirect me to there.